# check if a variable is in list

Tags: bash, shell, variable

to check if a word is in a list of words or no I wrote this script:

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]]' '\n' < t.txt |


while IFS= read -r word; do


if [[ "$word" =~ $(echo ^\($(paste -sd'|' ./champs.txt)\)$) ]]; then
```

but checking is not done. Even the word list was not checked any time

The file `t.txt` contains a list of sql query:

```
select * from student;
insert name, age, from professors;
delete from departement where DPTNUM= '20';
```

and the file `champs.txt` contains the query keywords

```
select
insert
into
values
delete
drop
from
create
table
where
set
varchar
number
```

Comment: can you paste the contents of t.txt and champs.txt and clarify what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I suspect it can be solved with a simple `grep`, but I would like to see an example of the contents of  `t.txt` and `champs.txt`.

Comment: when i have to put the grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear...

```
grep -owf champs.txt  t.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex-building command is a little bit wrong; besides, it's very inefficient to rebuild the same pattern on every loop iteration.

Although bash has a `read` command it's generally discouraged to use it for processing large amounts of text, since it's *very* slow, as well as being a common source of scripting errors. So try to restrict the use of `read` to processing simple user input.

As others have mentioned, this is a job for `grep`. Or if you want more control, consider using awk, which has good regex abilities. But if you *really* want to do it in a way similar to your posted code, here's one way to do it.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pat='^('$(paste -sd'|' champs.txt)')$'
printf "pattern: '%s'\n" "$pat"

IFS=
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < t.txt |
while read -r word; do
    if [[ "$word" =~ $pat ]]; 
        then echo "'$word' in list"
        else echo "'$word' NOT in list"
    fi
done
```

(The above script passes [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) analysis).

As you can see, we build the regex pattern `pat` *outside* the loop; I've added a `printf` to display the pattern so we can be sure it's what we want. Note that it's generally *much* better to use `printf` than `echo` to display arbitrary strings.

I've modified your `t.txt` to add a few extra test words, but used the same `champs.txt` as posted above.

**t.txt**

```sql
select * from student;
insert name, age, from professors;
delete from departement where DPTNUM= '20';
test number ins settle deleted
```

And here's the output:

```
pattern: '^(select|insert|into|values|delete|drop|from|create|table|where|set|varchar|number)$'
'select' in list
'*' NOT in list
'from' in list
'student;' NOT in list
'insert' in list
'name,' NOT in list
'age,' NOT in list
'from' in list
'professors;' NOT in list
'delete' in list
'from' in list
'departement' NOT in list
'where' in list
'DPTNUM=' NOT in list
''20';' NOT in list
'test' NOT in list
'number' in list
'ins' NOT in list
'settle' NOT in list
'deleted' NOT in list
```

Comment: thank you, but i used read because I must parse all the text file word by word,  and check every word and if that is not the case then I want to run other commands on the desired word.

Comment: @AomineDaiki. Understood, however you can do that more efficiently (and with more safety) using awk, which has great features for running shell commands. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/88378) for why using a shell loop to process text is considered bad practice, especially [Stéphane Chazelas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29)'s answer.

Comment: i do not know how to use awk to parse a text file word by word can you give me the command line please

Comment: @AomineDaiki: To learn how to use awk please consult its man page; there are also many free tutorials online. As with any language, it will take time to master it, but awk is a fairly small & simple language, and it shouldn't take you long to learn the basics. IMHO, awk is a lot more user-friendly than pure bash script, so it's a great addition to the skill set of any bash programmer.

Comment: @AomineDaiki: Here's a simple awk program that will print each whitespace-delimited word from one (or more) text files, with each word on a separate line. If no filenames are supplied on the commandline it will read from stdin. `awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)print $i}' filename`

Comment: thank you i now this but my goal is to execute some command line in each word. Where i can put this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22826/discussion-between-aomine-daiki-and-pm-2ring).