# Cut some fields from a text file to another

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

I have the following command:

```
grep -owf champs.txt  t.txt
```

and I want to cut  the result of this command from the file `t.txt` to another file.
I know that it can be achieved by a nested command but I do not know how to do it.

Note that in the file `t.txt`, I have:

```
select * from student
insert name age from professors 
delete from departement where DPTNUM= 20
```

and in the file `champs.txt` I have:

```
select
insert
into
values
delete
drop
from
create
table
where
set
varchar
number
```

so the desired result for the first line is:

```
* student
```

Comment: You can pipe the result to another command like this `grep -owf champs.txt  t.txt | <command2>`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input (`champs.txt` and `t.txt`) and your desired output. Also make sure you tell us how your fields are defined. Tabs? Spaces? Commas? Something else?

Comment: ¿Do you want to save the results of the command to a new file? Then you can use the command as: `grep -owf champs.txt  t.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: @terdon in this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195925/check-if-a-variable-is-in-list`` you can see the contains of the two files

Comment: @jcbermu not save but cut the result because the `grep` command is a verification of some fields

Comment: I don't want to look at another question. Each question should be self contained. Please [edit] and include all necessary information _here_. In any case, the other question does not include your desired output nor the contents of `t.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` way to achieve what you want:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { k[$1] ; next }
  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i in k) $i="" ; gsub(/ +/," ") }
  1
' champs.txt t.txt
```

(The `gsub` is just for convenience, it compresses sequences of blanks.)

For you sample data the result is:

```
 * student
 name age professors
 departement DPTNUM= 20
```